# Markdown # vs multiple #

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

I noticed that the use of `#` or `##` or `####` is equivalent... will the always be the case?

I want to use only a '#' sometimes because it is more convenient, as long as it doesn't become much bigger text in the future.

I'm not sure if this applies to generated documentation since I don't know how to generate it, I only found command line instructions but surely there must be an easier way from the IDE that I just haven't found yet.

Comment: p.s. unrelated - how can you escape `[` and `]` when I do `Hello [abc]` I run into problems with IDEA thinking abc is an identifier but really I need it to literally be brackets

Comment: You can escape `[` and `]`with `\`. I could not find documentation, but at least for the latter has a [test case][intellij-markdown/test/data/parser/linkDefinitions.md].

Comment: Edit to last post (after fighting with the markup in stackoverflow comments) -- @ycomp: You can escape `[` and `]`with \. I could not find documentation, but at least the latter has a [test case](http://intellij-markdown/test/data/parser/linkDefinitions.md). Obviously, the escape character is not consumed, but remains visible (at least in the Quick-Documentation). Moreover, you can always mark the respective region as `code`.